# Running Nightwatch test via tag, runs all test in the suite

Tags: tags, nightwatch.js

I want to run only one test from whole suite, and when I use tag all tests are run in that suite.

So in my dummy test you can see below, `nightwatch --tag search` suppose to run only "Search test" test, but it actually also run first test "What is your browser" test.

I have no Idea what might cause this behavior, would appreciate any suggestions.

[image: Nightwatch tag issue]

Answer (score 0):

@tags are meant to execute on module level. you are attempting on each function within a module hence the unexpected behavior.